# Find a basis that entries of vectors are linear combinations of $\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma$ satisfying $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta+\cos^2\gamma=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, for every $\alpha, \beta$ that satisfies $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta=1$, there exists a basis that each entry of each vector is a linear combination of $\cos\alpha,\cos\beta$. Explicitly, it is $(\cos\alpha, \cos\beta)$ and $(-\cos\beta, \cos\alpha)$. 
**My question:** In $\mathbb{R}^3$, is there a basis that entries of vectors are linear combinations of $\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma$ for every $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ that satisfies $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta + \cos^2\gamma=1$? Furthermore, what is it like in a higher dimension?
**My attempt:** I am trying to construct a $3\times3$ matrix that each entry is a linear combination of $\cos\alpha,\cos\beta,\cos\gamma$, and try to make its determinant equals $\cos^2\alpha+\cos^2\beta + \cos^2\gamma=1$, but I failed. 
I know that the determinant does not need to be 1, I just want to imitate the situation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In another way, what I want to know is whether there exists a $3\times 3$ matrix that all entries are linear combinations of $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$, and its determinant is always not zero for all  $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$ satisfying $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta +\cos^2\gamma = 1$.
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Why does the determinant need to be $1$? We don't say a vector is a linear combination of scalars, by the way.

Comment: @Quzs You say that there exists a basis that each vector is a linear combination of $\cos\alpha,\cos\beta$ and then give your example. What exactly do you mean when you say that the vector $(- \cos \beta, \cos \alpha)$ "is a linear combination of $\cos \alpha, \cos \beta$"? There is no standard interpretation of that sentence that makes it true.

Comment: my hunch is it's impossible since you require the entries be linear combinations and also require the $3\times 3$ determinant to be a degree $2$ polynomial. You can get close by getting $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta - \cos^2\gamma$ etc by doing some simple padding your $2\times 2$ with zeros and ones.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that the determinant does not need to be 1, I just want to imitate the situation in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In another way, what I want to know is whether there exists a $3\times 3$ matrix that all entries are linear combinations of $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$, and its determinant is always not zero for all  $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$ satisfying $\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2\beta +\cos^2\gamma = 1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, my expression is not accurate, I have edited my question. What I want to express is that each entry is a linear combination of $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$.

Comment: @dezdichado In fact, I only need the determinant to be non-zero for all $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$ satisfying the conditions, is it also impossible?

Comment: Are you allowing $0$ as a coordinate?

Comment: Use can use [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) and then convert all the $\operatorname{sin}$ to $\operatorname{cos}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin If you mean that one of $\cos\alpha, \cos\beta, \cos\gamma$ can be 0, actually, yes.

Comment: @mavzolej Can you explain your idea more specifically?

Comment: I still don’t know what a linear combination of numbers means. Whatever it means, $0$ is a linear combination of them without needing one of them to be $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes you are right, of course, 0 is a linear combination of them. Regarding linear combinations of them, I mean that considering they are variants of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, not only numbers because they can have different values, and all entries are like $2\cos\alpha + 3\cos\beta - \cos\gamma$, etc.

Comment: @Quzs your $3\times 3$ determinant will be a cubic, homogeneous multinomial in $x,y,z:$
$$\det A =  \sum_{i+j+k = 3, i,j,k\geq 0}c_{ijk}x^iy^jz^k.$$

You want this to be non-zero on the set $D = \{x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1\,\vert\, -1\leq x,y,z\leq 1.\}$ This general problem does not seem so easy for me (Keep in mind that $c_{ijk}$ are not arbitrary - they come from total of $27$ scalar coefficients).  

Your particular attempt was to look for $A$ such that $\det A = M(x^2+y^2+z^2)$, which cannot work since the LHS is homogeneous of degree $3$ and the RHS is of degree $2.$